# Two way data binding is not working for array in isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can not understand how two-way data binding works with directive`s isolated scope.

If i assign completely new object to some property in isolated scope, property in controllers scope is updated as well. How ever this is not the case with array. If i assign new array to property on the scope, the array is not updated in controller, futher more two way data binding is lost for this property. This can be confusing, please check [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JaZbvvKcORL81xyLh5G3?p=preview). 
Here is code from plunker, i am creating here two directives: one to for object assignment and other for array.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.object = {val: "initialized in controller"};
  $scope.array = ["initialized in controller"];

  $scope.changeArray = function ( ) {
    $scope.array = ['changed in controller'];
  }

  $scope.changeObject = function () {
    $scope.object = {val: "changed in controller"};
  }
});

app.directive ('array', function ()  {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: 'array in directive: {{value}} <br/> <button ng-click="click()">change array in directive</button>',
    scope: {
      value: '=*'
    },
    link: function (scope) {
      scope.click = function () {
        scope.value= ["changed in directive"];
      }
    }
  }
});

app.directive ('object', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: 'val in directive is: {{value}} <br/> <button ng-click="click()">change object in directive</button>',
    scope: {
      value: '='
    },
    link: function (scope) {
      scope.click = function () {
        scope.value = {val: 'changed in directive'};
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Why "=*" instead of just "="? Don't think I have ever seen that before, and it seems to work as intended without it.

Comment: @Erik Honn Firstly I tried "=", but this did not work for arrays, so i decided to try "$watchCollection" - "=*".

Comment: Then I am not sure I understand the problem. If you switch to a regular "="-binding your plunker looks to work fine for me.